# Bulma Extensions switch: how do I get it to switch

Tags: bulma

When I try to use my switch like the one in the [demo](https://wikiki.github.io/form/switch/), it doesn't move.

I can see it console log the click in my handler when I click it or use the spacebar when it's focused.

Since I'm loading these dynamically, I'm generating my id, name and label "for" with all the same value, IE: isActive-n.

The switch is loading properly on the page, it looks great, it just doesn't move. I've tried a few different id/label value formats and nothing works yet.

Here is the switch part of my react component:

```
      <div className="column is-2">
          <div className="field is-pulled-right">
            <input
              id={`isActive-${props.id}`}
              type="checkbox"
              name={`isActive-${props.id}`}
              className="switch is-success is-rounded"
              checked={checked}
              onChange={swithOnChangeHandler}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`isActive-${props.id}`}>{label}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<div class="column is-2">
    <div class="field is-pulled-right">
        <input id="isActive-11" type="checkbox" name="isActive-11" class="switch is-success is-rounded is-small">
        <label for="isActive-11">Activate</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a problem with the state of the input checked property. My logic for setting it was wrong. I also started using `true` and `false` for the checked value.